# how to force language in android application

Tags: android, locale

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Changing Locale within the app itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264874/changing-locale-within-the-app-itself)

in my application I need to "force" language let's say that I have locale in english as default polish and finnish, according to [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5348618/multi-language-android-application) I had created function posted also bellow, function is called in createActivity(), but the problem is it does not work.... any idea why? Any suggestions?

```
private void setLocale(String localeCode){
        Locale locale = new Locale(localeCode);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }
```

Answer (score 12):

Here is what I got so far. I know this question is resolved, but my solution is easier and more compact. No other changes are needed, no android:configurationChanges attribute for all activities in your manifest.

```
public class SigmaMiddleEastApplication extends PPGApplication {

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        newConfig.locale = Locale.ENGLISH;
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        Locale.setDefault(newConfig.locale);
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(newConfig, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }
}
```

**BEWARE this may cause problems:** 
[What could cause an Android activity to relaunch itself infinitely when returning from camera?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12503125/what-could-cause-an-android-activity-to-relaunch-itself-infinitely-when-returnin)

Comment: Just wrap everything around a  "if(newConfig.locale!=targetLocale)" should resolve the infinite relaunch problem.

Answer (score 3):

Add the following in the manifest (for every activity) :

```
android:configChanges="locale"
```

Comment: for this to work this must be coupled with the solution below (by Sergii)