# Android change language

Tags: android, onchange

I have two files: `strings.xml` (my native language) and `string2.xml` (English language). 
Is there a way to, on button click, load one of these files?

For example, on button click if I use file `strings.xml` then change the default to `string2.xml`. Or if I use `string2.xml`, then on click change to `string.xml`.

Comment: Android does that for you automatically depending on the device language. Just create a folder values-xy and put your strings.xml inside, where xy is the language code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Resources res = context.getResources();
DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
android.content.res.Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
conf.locale = new Locale(language_code.toLowerCase());
res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
```

use the above code to update Locale of the app. Just have two folders in res as values-en and values-yournativelanguge and place your string.xml in each folder with name string.xml .

Refer this [LINK](http://adrianvintu.com/blogengine/post/Force-Locale-on-Android.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

For using multiple language you can use the localization concept.

Here is the link of developer.android.com

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/localization/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [Load different strings.xml resource on Spinner change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7305928/load-different-strings-xml-resource-on-spinner-change)
It seems like it's possible but you'll have to change the whole locale language of your application.